Initialization issue of FMU from openmodelica on ADEVS
I use ADEVS(A Discrete EVent System simulator) to simulate fmu model, but after I have compiled the file with cmake, I run the generated executable file main, which runs the adevs_fmi.h function "status = _fmi2SetTime(c,t_now);"and then reports an error "void adevs::FMI::init(double*) [with X = adevs::PortValue<ExchangeData*>]: Assertion `status == fmi2OK' failed."
Hello, the ADEVS I use can simulate the fmi model, I use it to simulate the model. I generated the fmu model using OpenModelica Compiler v1.20.0. When you run the program with ADEVS, adevs reads the model's.soflie and initializes the model, but fails to run the fmisetTime function, which is to set startTime for the model, but it fails, I don't know why.The generated fmi model can be run in openmodelica simulation, but fails on adevs.

Have you tested to import the FMU with other FMI importing tools, especially the validation tools listed on https://fmi-standard.org/validation/ ?
The OpenModelica version that you use is outdated. The current version is v1.23.1 . In old OpenModelica versions, a lot of errors w.r.t to the FMI Implementation  have been reported. There seems to be much better FMI Support in recent OpenModelica Versions. Please use the latest one.
adevs is not listed on the FMI tools page (https://fmi-standard.org/), and the maturity of its FMI support is unknown. The documentation linked on https://web.ornl.gov/~nutarojj/adevs/ is not available. You could try to reach the developer mentioned at the end of https://web.ornl.gov/~nutarojj/adevs/
(Please tag your question also with "adevs"

I used FMU Check to check the FMU model I generated, and the result was "Validation passed. No problems found." It seems that the fmu model has no syntax errors. I haven't tried to simulate this model anywhere else.
As for tags, I tried to add the "adevs" tag, but there is no adevs tag in the existing tag, and I don't have permission to create a new tag

@rain FMU Check does a static check only, please try to simulate the FMU with one of the other validation tools listed on https://fmi-standard.org/validation/ such as fmpy oir fmusim
